# AzureDevOps onPremise, Workspacemapping really slow

Tags: performance, workspace, tfvc, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

We are using the onPremise version of the DevOps Server 2019 (curently update 1) with self-hosted agents (agents have the last version available from gitHub) in combination with TFVC (2019).
The devOps server is running in a virtual machine and the tfvc server is running in a different virtual machine.
The communication between them is fast, i tested this already by simply copying big testdata from one to the other over network. There is no Problem.

On each and every run, at the very beginning, the workspace mapping from a previous run is getting deleted, a new one is created and than a new workspace mapping to every source paths defined in the repository is established. This is taking about 30-60 Minutes on each and every pipeline/run.

We dont have only one single path in the repository defined. there are a lot of mappings, so that the amount of code that gets taken from TFS stays little and only represents that source code, that is needed by this executed solution.
This can't be changed and has to stay as it is, also we can't simply move to github. (Just sayin in case someone would like to advice to move to github :))

Are there any people, that experienced the same behaviour in the past, that the repository paths mapping at the fist build step is taking about 30-60 minutes when a build is executed?

thanks for any hints in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution now was, installing everything from scretch on a new machine.

After that, the mappings are running in a 10th of the time it took before